# a complex number equation

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $t,a\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|e^{i\theta} + at| = 1$ ($\theta$ is some real number),holds for all $|a|\le1$

Prove the only $t$ satisfy the equation is $t = 0$

It's easy to show it in a picture , how to prove it more rigor?

Comment: $$|e^{i\theta}+at|^2=1+|at|^2+2|at|\cos(\theta-\arg(at))$$

So, since $|e^{i\theta}+at|=1$, if $|at|\ne0$, then

$$|at|=-2\cos(\theta-\arg(at))$$

Comment: So, the thesis is not true unless there are restrictions on $t$ and $\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $$|e^{i\theta} + at| = 1 \text{ for all } |a|\leq 1$$Then for $a=e^{i\theta}$, you get that $|1+t|=1$, so there exists $\phi$ such that
$$t=e^{i\phi}-1$$

For $a=\frac{e^{i\theta}}{2}$, you get that $|2+t|=2$ so there exists $\psi$ such that
$$t=2(e^{i\psi}-1)$$

So $$e^{i\phi}-1 = 2(e^{i\psi}-1) , \quad \text{so} \quad e^{i\phi}+1=2e^{i\psi} , \quad \text{so} \quad |e^{i\phi}+1|=2$$

The only possibility is that $e^{i\phi}=1$, i.e. that $t=0$.